# Defect in updated Marshmallow

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow

Recently, i updated Samsung galaxy J5 to Marshmallow,Today when i tried to change lock screen password,like type previous password then enter new password and then confirmation of new password.I did these all steps and all goes well as they should be but when i lock my phone and try to enter password again it does not accept my new password it says password is incorrect.Then when i try old password it is accepted.What is this? Why phone is just stuck to one password and does not change password.By the way this old password was also in previous Lollipop version.
I have done "clear cache partition" in recovery mode but still the issue is same.
I googled this problem but there was not any matter of this kind.
Have you people any suggestion for this?

Comment: Probably a permissions issue. That's why you do a full wipe after upgrading the OS. You probably need to delete the `.key` files in `/data/system`. This requires root permission or a custom recovery.

Comment: I don't want to root device.There are many folders and files at back end and i don't know where is this key.Actually i found this system folder but there were many sub folders like "app","bin","lib","framework" etc.Now where is this key?Also i don't want to full wipe it after that it take much time to manage all apps again.Only option is key,can you provide full path of this key.I use ES file explorer to open system folders.

Comment: So the key files are at `/data/system` not `/system`. But unless you root your device, you are unable to do anything with those files.

Comment: Friend,rooting device is not appropriate for me i still remember when i rooted another android device,after rooting my phone become completely exposed to adds.Adds irritate too much.Although i removed root but adds remain.So,i will have to do full wipe.Let's see what will happen.

Comment: The ads don't come from rooting (unless you use some shady auto-root tool). But a full wipe should do the trick.

Comment: A big problem occurred,i made factory reset(wipe all data) then when phone  restarted again it asked me to enter previous e-mail address and password.Well i don't know previous e-mail address and password i just thought that i will made another google account after reset.I have another device kit kat it does not ask for previous e-mail and password when we perform a factory reset.I was not aware of this new security.Actually J5 is not my phone it is my father's phone,they don't use gmail account.They just use it for calling family and business.They even don't remember what is password.So now?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/43266/discussion-between-atif-iqbal-and-gianttree).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me give another clear answer with steps. It is based on this [you tube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Nv0qzD-NA7I&list=LLcZyErTpCdXutibbme4py6g&index=1)

I updated Samsung J5 to Marshmallow but there was problem then I did a factory reset to make it right but after reset it asks me to enter your previous e-mail and password. Well ,this phone belongs to my father. He didn't know password .Then I searched on Google and finally found a solution.Key steps are:

1. Download Odin software from [here](http://goo.gl/UXpLon)
2. Download Samsung J5 firmware.You have to download firmware whose date is before September 2015, from [here](http://www.sammobile.com/firmwares/)
3. Download Bypass [app](https://onedrive.live.com/?authkey=!AD7-ebCns6qfeyc&cid=909A907AB0E050A1&id=909A907AB0E050A1!2573&parId=909A907AB0E050A1!2572&action=locate)
4. OTG cable is required.

After downloading these three, grab your phone. Power it off then after few seconds press <kbd>Vol down</kbd>+ <kbd>home button</kbd>+ <kbd>power button</kbd>. After this a caution sign will appear,press <kbd>Vol up</kbd> button.Now your phone will go in downloading mode.
Connect your phone to PC via data cable,now launch Odin software on PC and click on `AP` button and select firmware which you have downloaded.It will say you to wait...then a message will appear as "`Leave CS`". When message appears ,click on <kbd>start button</kbd>. Firmware will now install to your phone,you will see loading line on phone and PC.When it completed android icon appears on phone. Now,remove data cable,after few seconds your phone will switch on.Now press few next button or skip them.When you reach on "verify your account" it will ask you to enter your e-mail.Since we *don't have email or password  save Bypass app in a USB and connect OTG cable to your mobile,after connecting OTG you will see that phone file manager will open USB on phone, install Bypass app (enable app install from unknown sources).Open this app,now you have access to settings, there go to factory reset and perform reset.Your phone will restart.Finally Google verify account has removed,after few steps your phone will switch on again.

**Note :**   Every thing works fine except two things:

1. Skype app does not connect to server network
2. You will not be able to do Software update

Comment: Thank you for adding steps, please delete the earlier answer. You can *accept* your answer after 48 hours by ticking the green mark below the answer

Comment: Thanks for editing and correction beeshyams. It looks better now.

Comment: You are welcome, you may like to edit your question also to make it look better and in future would be able to present better questions and answers. Please delete earlier answer